# Помогите создать массив в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, данный скрипт работает но не так как надо, он заносит в консоль результат по которому я кликнул, и при каждом клике новый скрипт, а я хочу в строку через запятую.
Помогите пожалуйста реализовать

```js
$(window).load(function() { //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится
  $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $("#basket").show("slow"); // показываем как откроется форма
    var ID = $(this).data('id'); // берет элемент по которому кликнули
    $.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
        url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
        data: {
          id: ID
        }, // данные которые передаются
        type: "POST", // метод
      })
      .done(function(data) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
        console.log(data); // выводим отладочную информацию
      });
  });
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вкладка _preview_ показывает **ответ** сервера, а не то, что ты отправляешь

Comment: то есть исправлять в php? в response тоже самое

Comment: @Koly на данный момент вы смотрите не вывод консоли.

Comment: @Koly чётко определитесь с логикой. По вашему вопросу не понятно, что вы хотите получить в итоге. Выбрать несколько элементов и по кнопке отправить их через запятую?

Comment: Всё зависит от того куда вам эти данные нужно заносить "через запятую", если в массив, то сначала объявите его `var array = [];` потом там, где получаете ответ от сервера добавляйте этот ответ в массив `array.push(data);`

Comment: да выбрать не сколько элементов, точнее три , вот и что бы myscript.php не повторялось , то есть создавался массив из того по чему кликнул человек

Comment: @Koly т.е. вы хотите, чтобы запрос отправлялся только когда *кликнули* по 3 элементам?

Comment: нет, максим три

Comment: @Koly а если например нажали на 1 и 2 элемент тогда что? как определить нужно отсылать запрос или нет?

Comment: есть кнопка сравнить, то есть столько есть столько и сравнивать

Comment: @Koly логика не сходится с Вашим кодом. в вашем примере вы кликаете на 1 элементу и получаете его `data-id`, т.е. получается вам нужно как минимум два скрипта: **1** - на добавление `data-id` элементов в массив при нажатии на элемент, **2** - на отправку запроса при нажатии на кнопку *сравнить*

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47761/discussion-between-koly-and-alex).

Comment: помогите в чате разобраться в чате

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(window).load(function() { //говорим скрипту что он сработает когда вся страница загрузится
  var ID = [];
  $('.test').click(function() {
    ID.push($(this).data('id'));
    console.log(ID);
  });
  $('.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.width').click(function(e) { //ловим клик
    $("#basket").show("slow"); // показываем как откроется форма
    console.log(ID);
    $.ajax({ // сам ajax запрос
        url: "myscript.php", // обработчик на php 
        data: {
          id: ID
        }, // даные которые передатся
        type: "POST", // метод
      })
      .done(function(data) { //отладочный запрос по которому заносятся данные 
        console.log(data); // выводим отладочную информацию
      });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-id="1">test1</div>
<div class="test" data-id="3">test2</div>
<div class="test" data-id="2">test3</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg width" type="button">сравнить</button>
```